graph-ts: where to config pg uri for set function
I am reading source codes of graph-ts.
from https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-tooling/tree/main/packages/ts, i saw
import { crypto, store } from '@graphprotocol/graph-ts'
// This is just an example event type generated by `graph-cli`
// from an Ethereum smart contract ABI
import { NameRegistered } from './types/abis/SomeContract'
// This is an example of an entity type generated from a
// subgraph's GraphQL schema
import { Domain } from './types/schema'

function handleNameRegistered(event: NameRegistered) {
  // Example use of a crypto function
  let id = crypto.keccak256(name).toHexString()

  // Example use of the generated `Entry` class
  let domain = new Domain()
  domain.name = name
  domain.owner = event.params.owner
  domain.timeRegistered = event.block.timestamp

  // Example use of the store API
  store.set('Name', id, entity)
}

I am curious about store.set('Name', id, entity) which save entity to pg table. but i did not see where the pg is configured. where is uri set?
Thanks
